# changing a property value in the model in swift

Tags: swift, properties, swiftui, toggle

I'm new to swift and having issues on how model classes and views interact. I'm trying implementing a toggle in the view that change the value of a property in a model class but in the struct I don't find the way implementing it:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DomandaRispostaView: View {

    @ObservedObject var dm: DataManager = DataManager.shared
    @ObservedObject var domandaRisposta : DomandaRisposta

    @State private var isEnabled1 = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(domandaRisposta.testoRisposta)
            Form {

                    Toggle(isOn: $isEnabled1) {
                        Text(isEnabled1 ? "Checked" : "Unchecked")
                        domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta == true
                    }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

the issue is at this line:

```
domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta == true
```

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: what is your goal by coding domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta == true? or did you want to write domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta = true? you cannot do "normal" coding in SwiftUI, you have to do it in "special" places or in functions. e.g. you can do coding in the action block of Button.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the help. My objective is that when I interact with the toggle button the value of domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta change from false to true. domandaRisposta is a simple class in the model with 3 properties: 1)a question 2)an answer 3) and "valoreRisposta" that's a Boolean if the answer is true or false. I'm trying to write an app to do a kind of survey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a separate `@State` variable to maintain the selection state. I have edited my code to add Codable conformance to the class as you needed.

```
class DomandaRisposta: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var valoreRisposta: Bool = false

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case valoreRisposta
    }

    init(valoreRisposta: Bool) {
        self.valoreRisposta = valoreRisposta
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        valoreRisposta = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .valoreRisposta)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(valoreRisposta, forKey: .valoreRisposta)
    }
}


struct DomandaRispostaView: View {
    @ObservedObject var domandaRisposta: DomandaRisposta

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta) {
           Text(domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta ? "Checked" : "Unchecked")
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case if you aren't already doing it, create the view using,

```
let rootView = DomandaRispostaView(domandaRisposta: model)
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, I obtain an "ambiguous use of valoreRisposta", so I 'm not able putting @published in the class. I put my class up in your code. r=Text as well it doesn't change

Comment: I see that you have "var valoreRisposta: Bool" still there inside your class. You have to replace that with "@Published var valoreRisposta: Bool = false". That is probably the reason for the error "ambiguous use of valoreRisposta"

The idea is to make "valoreRisposta" into a @Published variable.

Comment: I tried, the problem is that if I change "var valoreRisposta: Bool" with "@Published var valoreRisposta: Bool = false" I receive the error: Type 'ContentView.DomandaRisposta' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Comment: You have to make the @Published conform to Codable. That is a different problem altogether. Check this out - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/adding-codable-conformance-for-published-properties

Comment: I have also edited my answer to add Codable conformance. I suggest you read the article that I shared above.

Comment: thanks. having the real class not only one property "valoreRisposta" but many (and in some case with custom types) do I have to add all of them in CodingKeys and replicate 'required init' and func 'encode' for each of them the same way above?

Answer (score 0):

any reason why this would not work:

```
 Toggle(isOn: self.$domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta) {
    Text(self.domandaRisposta.valoreRisposta ? "Checked" : "Unchecked")
 }
```